# How to combine while loop in mysql to single update

Tags: mysql

I have a temporary table named _temp that contains orders that will be sent back to a webpage.  When this table is created it populates all the information except the number of photos in each order (currently it will set the number of photos to -1 so that I know it hasn't been updated).  I want to update the number of photos in each order to the correct number.  I have no idea how to do this without using a while statement and going through each order individually.  Here is the code I'm currently using which works fine but is very slow

```
SET _current_id = (SELECT old_id FROM _temp WHERE photos = -1 LIMIT 1);

WHILE (_current_id IS NOT NULL) DO
UPDATE _temp SET photos = (SELECT COUNT(f.id) FROM files f WHERE f.file_type = "orders" AND f.table_id = _current_id AND deleted = 0) WHERE old_id = _current_id;
SET _current_id = (SELECT old_id FROM _temp WHERE photos = -1 LIMIT 1);
END WHILE;
```

Comment: try something like this 
`update _temp  set photos = count(1) from files f join _temp t on f.table_id =  t.old_id`

Comment: Thanks, turns out I pretty much had the solution already.  Just replace _current_id with t.old_id and get ride of the while statement        update _temp t set t.photos = (SELECT COUNT(f.id) FROM files f WHERE f.file_type = "orders" AND f.table_id = t.old_id AND deleted = 0) WHERE old_id = t.old_id;

Answer (score 0):

```
update _temp t set t.photos = (SELECT COUNT(f.id) FROM files f WHERE f.file_type = "orders" AND f.table_id = t.old_id AND deleted = 0) WHERE old_id = t.old_id;
```